# Quadratic Forms Using Derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, diagonalization

[This link](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lagrange_method) says we can diagonalize a quadratic form

$$ f(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}x_i x_j, $$
$$a_{ij} = a_{ji}, a_{ii} \neq 0$$

using derivatives (?!!!) in a formula like

$$f(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{4a_{11}} (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1})^2 + f_1(\vec{x})$$

Is there a fully general formula with a proof, and can we derive and prove the [Jacobi method](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Jacobi_method) this way?

Comment: what is $f_1??$

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{1}{4a_{11}}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1})^2 + f(x) - \frac{1}{4a_{11}}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1})^2 = \frac{1}{4a_{11}}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1})^2 + f_1(x)$

Answer (score 1):

This is one step in diagonalizing by completing the square over and over. As long as $a_{11} \neq 0,$ the revised form
$$ f(x) - \frac{1}{4 a_{11} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \right)^2}  $$
is still a quadratic form, but no longer has any terms involving $x_1.$ Therefore the step can be repeated. As long as the revised diagonal entries never become zero, this works. If, at some intermediate step, the revised $a_{kk} = 0,$ other things need to be done.

Works: $f = x^2 + 5 xy - 17 y^2.$ Then the derivative $f_1 = 2x+5y,$ then $f_1^2 = 4x^2 + 20 xy + 25 y^2,$ and $(1/4) f_1^2 = x^2 + 5 xy + (25/4)y^2,$ so
$$f(x) - \frac{1}{4 a_{11} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} \right)^2} = - \frac{93}{4} y^2  $$

Does not work: $g = 2xy$

For an algorithmic method that works even when the eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix are very bad, see [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)